# Restart Pod from OpenShift Java REST Client

Tags: java, openshift

i'm trying to programmatically restart a Pod. First I've found some ways of doing this through the oc command line:

1. Delete the pod and a new Pod will be created: `oc delete pod postgresql-2-wz989`
2. Launch a new Deployment: `oc rollout latest dc/postgresql`

I think the second way is better because the deployment config name is static and doesn't change like the pod's name.

My question is how to do this using the Java Rest Client? It's not very clear to me how to use this client API.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you run ``oc`` with the option ``--loglevel=9`` it will show you what REST API calls it makes and then you can program/script up the same.

Comment: To those marking this question to be closed as is too broad, it isn't if you know the subject. It is actually quite specific.

Comment: BTW, I don't know what ``oc rollout`` does under the covers, but one trick you can use is to have an annotation on the deployment config, possibly on the pod template. Update the value of the annotation with the current date. Because that represents a configuration change, it should trigger a new deployment of the pods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking into account the hint from Graham Dumpleton regarding the use of `--loglevel=9` I got to a solution using the java client:

```
IClient client = new ClientBuilder("https://10.0.75.2:8443")
                    .withUserName("developer")
                    .withPassword("developer")
                    .build();
IProject project = client.getResourceFactory().stub(ResourceKind.PROJECT, "prj4testing");
IDeploymentConfig deploymentConfig = client.getResourceFactory().stub(ResourceKind.DEPLOYMENT_CONFIG, "postgresql", project.getName());
IDeploymentTriggerable capability = deploymentConfig.getCapability(IDeploymentTriggerable.class);
capability.setForce(true);
capability.setLatest(true);
capability.trigger();
```

I got to this solution through researching the source code from the client. I don't know if there are better ways to achieve this. Any comments are welcome.